# Use scripting language to generate Zipf-like samples

Tags: math, random, probability

Is there any scripting language function (like in `python` or `bash`) that samples from a zipf-like distribution, for exponent `0<a<=1`. Zipf-like distribution `p(a)` can be found, [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.zipf.html).

PS: I am aware of existence of numpy function that can generate zipf samples, but it's only for `a >1`.